# Java SocketAPI - Getting IOException on second write after remote disconnects

Tags: java, sockets

I am writing client socket which only writes to server. It does not read anything back. In this case, I am trying to figure out how to detect socket disconnection, if remote shutdowns/disconnects. I am using below implementation to write to server where writer is OutputStreamWriter object.

```
writer.write(message);
writer.flush();
```

What I am observing is, I always get socket error on second write after server shuts down. I am not getting error on first write which is done immediately after server shutdown.

Comment: That's as expected. You usually won't get it on the first write because of the socket send buffer.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne : So if I want to add retry on socket failure, there is no way I can add that for first write ??

Comment: You can't retry on a socket failure. You have to close the socket and start again. And you have to make sure your transactions are idempotent if you're going to retransmit them.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne: By retry, I mean creating socket again and push data, but to make that decision, what can be the option for first write ?

Comment: There isn't one. I would have thought I had already made that clear.